# Automatic save after select

Tags: grails

I noticed that invoking service method with simple select makes MyDomain.class Date field update in DB (clears time). However enclosing the method with @Transactional(readOnly = true) doesn't update the date value.

Why the value is saved into DB?

Here is the service method

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Date getDate() 
{
    Date date = null
    date = MyDomain.executeQuery("select min(s.startDate) from MyDomain s where ....)[0]
    print "Result: " + date

}
```

Comment: provide definition of your MyDomain class, it's possible you have defined it in a way that it updates itself on read. Also.. is it possible that your query returns different objects, thus the date is different?

Answer (score 2):

The object will only get updated in the database if it is somehow changed after it brought into the hibernate session (selected) and before the the session is closed (usually at the end of the method). Take a look at your object, and see how it might be modified in some way that you did not intend.

Comment: Actually the object isn't changed. I've added print statement to check the result retrieved from database before the transaction ends.
And the results are as below:
1. Without @Transactional(readOnly = true) Result: 2012-10-20 00:00:00.0 
2. With @Transactional(readOnly = true): 2012-10-20 17:00:00.0